# HTML reset dropdown select menu to default value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, placeholder

I have a select menu like this:

The first `option` tag is my placeholder and gets deactivated if I click the select menu.

```js
$('select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    $this.addClass('select-hidden');
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
    $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
    });

    $listItems.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        console.log($this.val());
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
    <select id="office-select">
        <option value="hide"><a>choose a number</a></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
    </select>
    <button class="resetbtn" type="submit">X</button>
</div>
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/conp2bqr/).
Imagine we choose the number 6, then something is displayed on the bottom of the screen. After that I want to click the button to reset my select menu. So the text `choose a number` should be displayed as placeholder again.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing in the ```$('select').each(function()``` function but I wrote a function after yours which is working. Check it out on this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6801q573/14/). Unfortunately I had to comment out your function for mine to work. Maybe try enabling your function piece by piece and see what is causing my function to stop working then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once option selected, `.select-options` is hidden by `.next('ul.select-options').hide();`

You need to show it again on `.resetbtn` click

```
$('.resetbtn').click(function() {
    $('.select-styled').html("<a>choose a number</a>");
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it